# Selenide tests hang in Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, selenide

I'm experiencing a problem running Selenide tests in Firefox version 46. When tests run separately everything works fine. But when I run all test methods in class it hangs on the following step:

```
addons.productaddons INFO sending request to: https://aus5.mozilla.org/update/3/GMP/46.0/20160421124000/WINNT_x86_64-msvc-x64/en-US/release/Windows_NT%206.1.1.0%20(x64)/default/default/update.xml
addons.productaddons INFO Completed downloading document
addons.productaddons INFO Downloading from https://cdmdownload.adobe.com/firefox/win/x64/primetime_gmp_win_x64_gmc_40673.zip to C:\Users\hunar_letsko\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpaddon
addons.productaddons INFO Downloading from http://ciscobinary.openh264.org/openh264-win64-0410d336bb748149a4f560eb6108090f078254b1.zip to C:\Users\hunar_letsko\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpaddon
addons.manager INFO Skipping background update check
DeferredSave.extensions.json DEBUG Save changes
DeferredSave.extensions.json DEBUG Starting timer
DeferredSave.extensions.json DEBUG Starting write
DeferredSave.extensions.json DEBUG Write succeeded
```

One more note: when test method are running more than 3 hours of hanging it fails with connection timeout:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Build info: version: '3.0.0', revision: '350cf60', time: '2016-10-13 10:48:57 -0700'
System info: host: 'EPBYMINW2815', ip: '10.6.9.56', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
selenide.url: app_url"
selenide.baseUrl: http://localhost:8080

 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteNavigation.to(RemoteWebDriver.java:902)
 at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.Navigator.navigateToAbsoluteUrl(Navigator.java:69)
 at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.Navigator.open(Navigator.java:31)
 at com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open(Selenide.java:81)
 at com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open(Selenide.java:55)
 at
```

where `app_url` is my application's url.

Thanks for any help in advance, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to downgrade Selenide. Selenide 4.0 works bad with Firefox.